# Map type Declaration difference

Tags: java, types, declaration, variable-declaration

What's the difference between

```
Map<String, String> exemple = new HashMap<>();
```

And

```
Map<String, String> exemple = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically, neither is valid Java. They should be

```
Map<String, String> example = new HashMap<>();
```

or

```
Map<String, String> example = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

There's no real difference between the two in Java 7 and 8. However, the first example is not valid in Java versions prior to Java7, which introduced a limited amount of type inference in the Java compiler and made explicitly declaring the type parameters unnecessary in some places.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html

Most IDEs will highlight the second form of the statement as involving unnecessary duplication these days. However, it's not an error and they are both declaring exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

About your first statement (provided you have round brackets at the end):

- Starting java 7, key and value type is [inferred](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) by compiler and hence you dont need to specify the parameter type on the right hand side.
- This code would compile well on JDK7 and 8.

About your second statement(provided you have round brackets at the end):

- Until Java6, you would have to explicitly specify the type of key and value on the right hand side of your construction of HashMap.
- This code would compile well on JDK5 and later.